# VAR model with R, stationarity

Tags: r, time-series, prediction

so using a model var with the package 'vars' for R, in this way:

```
model_var <- VAR(my_data, lag.max=10)
roots(model_var)
pred <- predict(model_var, n.ahead=15)
```

if my_data is stationary there are no problems.
But, if my_data is not stationary, I differencing all the time series in my_data, it's correct?
Now, I work with differencing data, and the prediction is made with this data.
For I return to the original data for the prediction, how should I use the operator diffinv()?

Thanks!

Luca

Answer (score 2):

Your data should have the class "ts". If you data is a matrix called data

> class(data)
>
> [1] "mts" "ts"
>
> ddata <- diff(data)

Now you can return your data to levels with

> diffinv(ddata, xi=t(data[1,]))

So your predicted values comes out in differences, then your return them with, e.g.

> diffinv(pred$fcst$VARIABLENAME[1,], xi=t(data[nrow(data),"VARIABLENAME"])

using the last observation of your data as the initial value, you can return the forecast to levels. where nrow(data) is the last row, and "VARIABLENAME" is the column of the variable you are interested in. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

@user21240. Since I don't have enough score to comment on your answer. I am writing it here as a post.

Technically what you said is correct. i.e `diff()` and `diffinv()` work exactly like this on any series. But is this the correct way of returning the forecast to levels, especially in the context of VAR .

Some clarification with symbolic notation might be very helpful, because even I am stuck with same problem.